# Block IP requesting xmlrpc.php

Tags: security, mod-security

We have a firewall with modsecurity installed. I would like to write a rule to block any IP address for 24 hours if that IP requests `xmlrpc.php`. Please note that we do not use WordPress on our platform but these requests are consuming huge amounts of traffic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Standard .htaccess Block*

I covered this a while back on my blog about [stopping WP brute force attacks](https://www.bybe.net/ways-to-stop-wordpress-brute-force-attacks/), you can IP block [xmlrpc.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) by using [`<Files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files), or [`<FilesMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch), here's what I use:

```
<Files "xmlrpc.php">
    Order Allow,Deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

The above code will block any requests that attempt to fetch that file.

*Modsecurity*

If you need more of an advanced solution that uses that mod_security then I recommend that you use [rate limiting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131681/how-can-i-implement-rate-limiting-with-apache-requests-per-second), something like this:

> [**SOURCE**](http://johnleach.co.uk/words/1073/rate-limiting-with-apache-and-mod-security)
>
> ```
> SecRuleEngine On
>
> <LocationMatch "^/somepath">
>   SecAction initcol:ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR},pass,nolog
>   SecAction "phase:5,deprecatevar:ip.somepathcounter=1/1,pass,nolog"
>   SecRule IP:SOMEPATHCOUNTER "@gt 60" "phase:2,pause:300,deny,status:509,setenv:RATELIMITED,skip:1,nolog"
>   SecAction "phase:2,pass,setvar:ip.somepathcounter=+1,nolog"
>   Header always set Retry-After "10" env=RATELIMITED
> </LocationMatch>
>
> ErrorDocument 509 "Rate Limit Exceeded"
> ```

However, unless you actually use XMLRPC for real purposes, there should be no reason why you should use a rate limiter for a file that either doesn't exist, or isn't needed.

*Fail2ban Rocks*

If you have root access to your host then I strongly recommend [Fail2ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban), since its more flexible, has way more features and is lot easier to use than mod_security.

*WordPress Users*

Users that use both [xmlrpc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) and WordPress should protect their wp-login.php since it is normally a [bruteforce attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack), therefore you should also make the extra effort to lock down your wp-login.php from also being attacked, I use this:

```
<FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
    deny from all
    # Broadband that changes IP ADDRESSES
    # Change the below to the domain that your broadband IP resolves too
    allow from .isp.com
    # Broadband that IP does not change
    allow from 1.1.1.1
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: The Rate limiting option looks good.  We can't use .htaccess as this is a third party firewall with modsecurity installed.  Is it possible to simplify the rate limiting option to achieve what I requested originally?  That is - if a user requests xmlrpc.php then block that IP for 24 hours?